# RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: ENOENT

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer, form-data

I got this error when using multer to save an image.
I am trying to use FormData to send image in a POST request with the fetch API. So back-end send me this error, and front-end send me unexpected token < at position 0 because of back-end incorrect response.

This is my code:

```js
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');
const { v1: uuidv1 } = require('uuid');

const MIME_TYPE_MAP = {
    'image/png': 'png',
    'image/jpeg': 'jpeg',
    'image/jpg': 'jpg'
}

const fileUpload = multer({
    limits: 500000,
    storage: multer.diskStorage({
        destination: (req, file, cb) => {
            cb(null, path.join(__dirname, 'uploads/images'));
        },
        filename: (req, file, cb) =>  {
            const ext = MIME_TYPE_MAP[file.mimetype];
            cb(null, uuidv1() + '.' + ext);
        }
    }),
    fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
        const isValid = !!MIME_TYPE_MAP[file.mimetype];
        const error = isValid ? null : new Error('Invalid mime type!');
        cb(error, isValid);
    }
});

module.exports = fileUpload;
```

And here I'm using the above code:

```js
const express = require("express");
const { body } = require("express-validator");

const fileUpload = require('../middleware/file-upload');

const router = express.Router();

router.post(
  "/signup",
  fileUpload.single('image'),
  body("name").not().isEmpty(),
  body("email").normalizeEmail().isEmail(),
  body("password").isLength({ min: 6 }),
  (req, res) => {
    res.json({user: req.body})
  }
);

module.exports = router;
```

The frontend:

```js
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('name', formState.inputs.name.value);
formData.append('email', formState.inputs.email.value);
formData.append('password', formState.inputs.password.value);
formData.append('image', formState.inputs.image.value);

const responseData = await fetch(
  "http://localhost:5000/api/users/signup",
  {
    method: "POST",
    body: formData
  }
);
```

[image]

Thanks for helping me.